# Как обновить внутренний объект с помощью hibernate?

Tags: java, база-данных, hibernate, jpa, orm

У меня имеются два класса:

**TimeTrackingDto**

```
public class TimeTrackingDto {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "time_spent_minutes")
    private Integer timeSpentMinutes;

}
```

**ProjectDto**

```
public class ProjectDto {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_time_tracking")
    private TimeTrackingDto timeTracking;

}
```

Мне нужно обновить объект класса ProjectDto, но проблема в том, что в TimeTrackingDto я передаю id null:

```
TimeTrackingDto timeTracking = new TimeTracking(null, timeSpentMinutes);
ProjectDto project = new ProjectDto(id, timeTracking);

Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
try {
  session.beginTransaction();
  session.saveOrUpdate(project);
  session.getTransaction().commit();
} catch (HibernateException e) {
  session.getTransaction().rollback();
}
```

Само собой когда hibernate видит, что id выставлен null, то он создает новую запись. Из-за этого когда я пытаюсь обновить ProjectDto, в базе данных каждый раз появляется новая запись TimeTrackingDto. Есть ли какой-нибудь механизм, который бы позволил обновлять внутренние объекты если у них id равен null?

Comment: Получите нужный вам объект из бд, обновите его поля и сохраните его в бд.

Comment: Именно так я сейчас и делаю, но хотелось бы без лишних обращений к бд.

Comment: По другому никак.

Comment: Надо триггер на вставку поставить, в котором обновлять

Answer (score 0):

Оптимальным решением будет создать запрос, который будет возвращать нужный объект ProjectDto (например по полю id, т.к. вы, видимо, получаете его значение заранее) и работать с ним.

В вашем случае, каждый раз, когда вы инициализируете оба объекта, hibernate думает, что это новые объекты. Т.к. вы вызываете saveOrUpdate, то он находит в таблице объектов ProjectDto, запись со значением id и перезаписывает и само значение и дочерние значения. В случае вызова метода save, скорее всего, он кинет ошибку, что запить с таким id уже есть.

P.S. Вы уверены, что у ваше TimeTrackingDto.id может быть null. Вы сделали его первичным ключом таблицы (@Id, что не дает ему быть null) и в добавок прописали генератор. Обычно использую конструкторы без id, потому что hibernate сам их создает.

P.P.S. Если вы, в конструкторе объекта TimeTracking, вместо null, укажете id существующей записи, то saveOrUpdate сработает успешно. Это дает вам возможность создавать новые записи объектов ProjectDto с уже существующими значениями записей объекта TimeTracking.